# Put column data in rows grouped by ID

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, textjoin

Difficult to put this in a question, but this is what I mean:

```
This is my data:
ID  DATA1  DATA2  DATA3  DATA4
1   yes    yes           yes
2          yes    yes
3   yes                  yes
```

What I like to get:

```
ID1
- DATA1
- DATA2
- DATA4
ID2
- DATA2
- DATA3
ID3
- DATA1
- DATA4
```

Anyone knows what query or formula I can use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("♦"; 1; {
 IF(A2:A<>""; A1&A2:A; )\ IF(B2:E="yes"; "- "&B1:E1; )}); "♦")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Can't make this work. Even if I literally copy the formula i get an error: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R1_aSTanKnu-19_lEydoDB9tPPljM4n0reV-J5blj0U/edit?usp=sharing